# Issues running async tasks in Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have minimal experience with Node.js projects and have inherited one which uses Gulp to build and distribute itself.

The project has several disparate task files, and a `gulpfile.js` which references them all. For brevity, I will use the smallest function as an example.

```
//gulpfile.js
...
gulp.task('csscompile', function() {        
  gulp.src('./src/ops/gulp/csscompile.js')
});
...


//csscompile.js
...
module.exports = function (gulp) {

  gulp.task('csscompile', function (done) {

    let paths = [
      'src/app/**/*.scss',
      'node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.scss',
    ];

    gulp.src(paths)
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(concat('app.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
      .done();
  });
};
```

Running `$ gulp csscompile` from the command line always completes the entire function in about 10ms, and I get output like:

```
[10:44:43] The following tasks did not complete: csscompile
[10:44:43] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Obviously there is an issue with waiting for the functions to complete. After searching around I have tried every imaginable combination of using `async` flags, using `function (done)`, and more, to no avail. Even putting the `csscompile` function directly in the `csscompile` task does not work.

I assume using `gulp.src()` is part of the issue, I don't know whether those functions are inlined or what. I also want to avoid having to turn every one of these functions into a `Promise`.

Does anyone have any recommendations of changes I can make?

Comment: Did you put a return in the `gulp.task('csscompile', function() {        
  return gulp.src('./src/ops/gulp/csscompile.js')
});` function too?  That may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion/#no-synchronous-tasks):

> When you see the "Did you forget to signal async completion?" warning, none of the techniques mentioned above were used. You'll need to use the error-first callback or return a stream, promise, event emitter, child process, or observable to resolve the issue.

So you need to return the stream.

This should work:

```
module.exports = function (gulp) {

  gulp.task('csscompile', function () {

    let paths = [
      'src/app/**/*.scss',
      'node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.scss',
    ];

    return gulp.src(paths)
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(concat('app.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for that link. I have tried your suggestion to return the stream, but I still get that "Did you forget...?" message. Could it be a problem with how I'm defining the task in `gulpfile.js`?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is a road to nowhere at the moment. Let me google it.

Comment: What version of gulp are you using?

Comment: v4.0.2. From what I can tell, this was all built ~v3.9.

Comment: There were breaking changes between Gulp 3 and 4 that require changes: https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/complete-guide-upgrading-gulp-4/

You'll have to use Gulp 3 or rewrite to use Gulp 4.